# How To Get Absolute Value / Absolute Sum and Window Functions

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a numeric column and I want to find the total % of what each value is of the total sum but I want to do it with absolute values. The query I want to run is below, but I get an error saying I can't use both aggregation functions and non aggregated fields. Also I don't want to use any joins, so I'm not sure if this is possible. Maybe I can use window functions but I'm not familiar with them. Any help with this query or explaining window functions would be greatly appreciated.

```
select ABS(val) / SUM(ABS(val)) from table
```

Comment: absolute values to avoid negatives?

Answer (score 2):

Completely agree with Felipe's comment above (obviously, as he is a Dev. Advocate for Big Data at Google. Loved your episode on the GCP Podcast, Felipe!), but in the interest of providing a bit more explanation, I'll add my two cents.

I was also very confused by window functions when I first started using BigQuery, but the most important little nugget in Felipe's comment is the empty `OVER()` statement. This essentially provides an "Open Window" function, so it does not partition your data, order your data, or provide a window frame clause. This allows you to perform a `RATIO_TO_REPORT()` over your entire column.

So basically, your query becomes as simple as:

```
SELECT ABS(number) AS abs_num, RATIO_TO_REPORT(abs_num) OVER()
FROM [dataset.project]
```

to get both the absolute value and the relative ratio it holds in the column without having to dive too deep into the full features of the window functions.

Read up on the [Query Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions) section about window functions to learn more. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! This really cleared things up. Just out of curiosity, what if I wanted to do something like using the absolute value of column a / sum of absolute column b? Ratio_To_report looks like it only uses the 1 column

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this is with a sub-select, like so  `SELECT abs_num/num2_sum
FROM(
SELECT ABS(number) AS abs_num, SUM(ABS(number2)) OVER() AS num2_sum
FROM [dataset.tablename]
)` There is very likely a more elegant way to accomplish this, but the subselect is relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like:

```
SELECT ABS(x) abs_x, RATIO_TO_REPORT(abs_x) OVER() ratio
FROM (SELECT 3 x),(SELECT 4 x),(SELECT -2 x),(SELECT 1 x),(SELECT 7 x), (SELECT 1 x)
```